# DB2 Tables Not Loading when run in Batch

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have been working on a reporting database in DB2 for a month or so, and I have it setup to a pretty decent degree of what I want. I am however noticing small inconsistencies that I have not been able to work out.

Less important, but still annoying: 
**1)** Users claim it takes two login attempts to connect, first always fails, second is a success. (Is there a recommendation for what to check for this?)

More importantly:
**2)** Whenever I want to refresh the data (which will be nightly), I have a script that drops and then recreates all of the tables. There are 66 tables, each ranging from 10's of records to just under 100,000 records. The data is not massive and takes about 2 minutes to run all 66 tables.

The issue is that once it says it completed, there is usually at least 3-4 tables that did not load any data in them. So the table is deleted and then created, but is empty. The log shows that the command completed successfully and if I run them independently they populate just fine.

If it helps, 95% of the commands are just `CAST` functions.

While I am sure I am not doing it the recommended way, is there a reason why a number of my tables are not populating? Are the commands executing too fast? Should I lag the `Create` after the `DROP`?

```
(This is DB2 Express-C 11.1 on Windows 2012 R2, The source DB is remote)
```

Example of my SQL:

```
DROP TABLE TEST.TIMESHEET;

CREATE TABLE TEST.TIMESHEET AS (

SELECT NAME00, CAST(TIMESHEET_ID AS INTEGER(34))TIMESHEET_ID ....
```

.. (for 5-50 more columns)

```
FROM REMOTE_DB.TIMESHEET

)WITH DATA;
```

Comment: Do some debugging. Prove that for the table that are unexpectedly empty that the source-table is not empty, and that there are no errors during the 'create table as ... with data' steps.  Examine the db2diag.log file.  Don't write "...first always fails...", but do write *exactly what the error code is*, again cross reference to db2diag.

Comment: The first error is annoying, but not my focus at the moment, just trying to paint a more full picture (not sure if it was related in any way because authentication might have been tied at all to pulling from the remote DB source).

The source tables are not empty, and no errors come up. All commands finish without errors.

Comment: And the db2diag entries that appear when the table(s) are unexpectedly empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to configure DB2 to tolerate certain SQL errors in nested table expressions.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/iiyfqetnint.html

> When the federated server encounters an allowable error, the server allows the error and continues processing the remainder of the query rather than returning an error for the entire query. The result set that the federated server returns can be a partial or an empty result.

However, I assume that your `REMOTE_DB.TIMESHEET` is simply a nickname, and not a view with nested table expressions, and so any errors when pulling data from the source should be surfaced by DB2.  Taking a look at the db2diag.log is likely the way to go - you might even be hitting a Db2 issue.

It might be useful to change your script to `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` into your local tables and see if that helps avoid the issue.

As you say you are maybe not doing things the most efficient way. You could consider using cache tables to take a periodic copy of your remote data https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.data.fluidquery.doc/topics/iiyvfed_tuning_cachetbls.html

Comment: for anyone with this issue: I fixed it by moving to MQT's instead of tables and running `REFRESH TABLE`. 


My understanding is that the `DROP` || `CREATE` commands are not executed as one would initially expect. A `DROP` command is accepted and then queued:


`DROP TABLE REMOTE.X`
`Command Completed Successfully` <-- At this point the command is queued but the table might still be exist for a short time
'CREATE TABLE X' <-- The table might not be fully deleted yet.


`TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` do not process in this way and are less intensive so saw less of this error.

Comment: I am accepting the answer because as mentioned above the `TRUNCATE` command executes better in scripts and is less resource-intensive and did improve my situation, but the ultimate solution in my use-case was to migrate to an almost entirely MQT database. the `REMOTE_DB.TIMESHEET` is indeed a nickname to work with federation. Due to data type restrictions on MQT's not allowing for CLOBS I do have 3 tables, they all use the `TRUNCATE` || `INSERT` function to avoid the error (plus a short pause in the script for safe measure ;-)  .